# Procedure call error in php the second time

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I need help.

I have a stored procedure (no parameters) operating in my MySQL (phpMyAdmin) data, this procedure returns many rows. I call this process PHP mysql_query and work the first time, but if you re-access the page or reloads the page, the error message: "commands out of sync you can not run this command now procedure"

Then, I copied the code so that you can help me:

The stored procedure is:

[stored procedure on PhpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqqUL.png)

And my PHP file is:

```html
<?php require_once('../Connections/PARTEGEST.php'); ?>
<?php
//---------------ADRIAN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
mysql_select_db($database_PARTEGEST, $PARTEGEST);
$query_partesPorObra = "CALL seguimientoHorasTotalesObra()";
//SI SE QUIERE MOSTRAR TODOS LOS OPERARIOS QUE HAN HECHO PARTES DE UNA OBRA EN CONCRETO Y CUANTO LLEVA CADA UNO DEDICADO A ESA OBRA, AGRUPAR POR PARTES.OPERARIO Y HABILITAR
//EL CAMPO OPERARIO EN LA TABLA, CON EL NOMBRE (OPERARIOS.NOMBRE)
$partesPorObra = mysql_query($query_partesPorObra, $PARTEGEST) or die(mysql_error());
$row_partesPorObra = mysql_fetch_assoc($partesPorObra);
$totalRows_partesPorObra = mysql_num_rows($partesPorObra);
?>

<!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
<script src="../bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
  <h1 class="page-header">Seguimiento Horas Totales de Obras</h1>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
 <div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading">Horas Totales por Obra</div>
  <!-- /.panel-heading -->
  <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
    <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>OBRA</th>
        <th>ESTADO</th>
        <th>HORAS</th>
        <th>H.ASIGNADAS</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php do {      
       echo "<tr class='gradeA'>";      
       echo "<td>".$row_partesPorObra['descripcion']."</td>";
       if($row_partesPorObra['finalizado']=="Y"){
        echo "<td class='center'>".$row_partesPorObra['finalizado']="Cerrado"."</td>";
       }
       else{
        echo "<td class='center'>".$row_partesPorObra['finalizado']="Abierto"."</td>";
       }
       echo "<td class='center'><center><b>".$row_partesPorObra['hours']."h</b></center></td>";
       echo "<td class='center'><center><b>".$row_partesPorObra['horas']."h</b></center></td>";
       echo "</tr>";
      } while ($row_partesPorObra = mysql_fetch_assoc($partesPorObra));?>
     
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
   </div>
</div>      

<?php
mysql_free_result($partesPorObra);
?>
```

Please helpme, it's for my job.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

When you call to a stored procedure it will return one or more result sets, each of which may have its own set of rows.

In your case you must use `mysql_next_result($connection)` after `mysql_free_result` statement, and then you can call a stored procedure again using the same connection.